# Defining constant with function in C

Tags: c, constants

I am trying to define a constant with the help of a function in the same C file.

I want to define a constant:

```
#define a 2
#define b 5
#define power PowerOf(a,b)
```

when PowerOf is a function I implement Later on in the code, with the signature:

```
int PowerOf(int base,int exp)
```

I also declare on it in the begining of the Code.

Can I do that? because when I try, the complier gives me an error as follows:

> [Error] variable-sized object may not be initialized

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Because the [macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) are expanded by the preprocessor before the compile phase. They must be compile time constants. You could however make both `a` and `b` `const int` then they would be integer constants.

Comment: I see...
unfortanately my assigment has one of the consts already defined with #define in H file that I am not allowed to change. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

This is very dangeorous and error-prone:

```
#define a 2
#define b 5
```

Whenever you will include this file, all `a` and `b` variables will be substituted with these values!

Comment: you maybe right, but it does not attempt to answer a question. Also, OP may have used `a` and `b` instead of `POWER` and `BASE` to shorten it.

Comment: They are just dummy variables, I do not really use them in my functions. It was just an example to the problem I got.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is simply a macro substitution - not a real constant.

In a way you are trying to do it, your `#define power ...` cannot be a constant - it will be still called at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other answers that this is an odd/ inappropriate /error prone way to use defines.  Here is a working program that does what you asked in the original question

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 7
#define B 2


int powerOf(double x, double y);

#define SUPERPOWER powerOf(A,B)


int main() {
   printf("%d", SUPERPOWER);
   return 0;
}

int powerOf(double x, double y) {
    return (int)trunc(pow(x,y));
}
```